# Crystal Report Formular always return Boolean

Tags: crystal-reports

iN my Crystal Report i have two columns of currency data types. I want to add a formular to the column a . i.e "WHEN A CURRENCY IN A is > THAN B, THEN The value of A should euqal the value of B ". I wrote my formula as below

```
currencyVar formular := {ProcName.coll};
IF({ProcName.coll} > {ProcName.ref}) 
Then 
    formular = {ProcName.ref}
```

AND

```
IF({ProcName.coll} > {ProcName.ref}) 
    Then 
        {ProcName.coll}= {ProcName.ref}
```

Both yielded the same boolean values.When I saved and named the formula above, i then insert the formula to my column . However, the result are all boolean True/False. I am ot sure how this  happened i check the data type of the formula is indicating boolean as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because you're testing equality not assigning the value as you wish to do. Change your last line to a statement of assignment by adding a colon before the equal sign:

```
...
    formular := {ProcName.ref}
    //       ^
```

Comment: Hi Thank you for the Reply . When i modified to this , it says there is an error in this formula.                                                                        `CurrencyVar currency:={ProcName.coll};
IF({ProcName.coll} >= {ProcName.ref})
 Then 
     currency:={ProcName.ref};`

Comment: It is difficult to help further without knowing the values of the various elements.

Comment: The error usually will give you a hint as to which part of the formula is causing a problem.

Comment: Thank you Benrie. Like you said it does give hint and i figured it out .